# Intellij 13 - Why pom.xml for a project?

Tags: eclipse, maven, intellij-idea, pom.xml

I am using Intellij IDE 13 since 2-3 days and came from Eclipse. 
So I create a project as a workspace and a module like a project in eclipse. All good..

But why does the project itself have a "pom.xml"? 
I am using all maven projects with its own pom.xml or can I define all common stuff there? java-version, encoding?

Thanks for help

---

Ok, maybe my question is a little bit confuse. 
I have a project called "MyProject" with the modules "Mod1" and "Mod2". The project is a maven project and the modules tool.
Here is the structure:

```
 MyProject
 -- Mod1
 ---- Mod1.imp // Intellij stuff
 ---- pom.xml // Maven configuration for Mod1
 -- Mod2
 ---- Mod2.imp // Intellij stuff
 ---- pom.xml // Maven configuration for Mod2
 - MyProject.iml  // Intellij stuff
 - pom.xml // Why this pom.xml?
```

All stuff is defined in the modules or is it a global pom.xml where I can define thinks like version or compiler for all other pom.xml?

Thanks for help

Comment: Maven project has pom.xml inside in general ;)

Comment: Yes, the pom includes all sorts of things like java-version, source file encoding, etc.

Answer (score 1):

The pom.xml is the Maven configuration file for a project.

See the [POM reference](http://maven.apache.org/pom.html).